# Installing npm package from git repo doesn't work as expected

Tags: node.js, git, npm

I've got a node application that I would like to install and run as a global package on my machine.
I host it on a private git repo.

So what I'm doing is I try `npm install -g git+https://<package>:<token>@gitlab.com/myName/repo.git` .

The install is successful, at least it seems to be.

When I list the globally installed packages though instead of seeing `package@version` I see `package@./../../../.././npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone<RandomNumbersAndLetters>`

And trying to run it using the command `<PackageName>` just returns a `command not found: <PackageName>`.

For other globally installed packages it looks correct.
`npm ls -g` gives `npm@9.5.1`.

What is going on here?

Comment: Maybe try `npx <package_name>`.